# New Xcode 14 beta I got this error: QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED waiting on a lower QoS thread running at QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app is working well and I didn't get this error on Xcode 13, But in Xcode 14 I'm getting this error from Firebase Database.

[Firebase Database Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdXV5.png)

```
Backtrace
=================================================================
3   FirebaseDatabase                    0x000000011267c6eb -[_FSRRunLoopThread runLoop] + 43
4   FirebaseDatabase                    0x000000011267c443 __45+[NSRunLoop(FSRWebSocket) FSR_networkRunLoop]_block_invoke + 115
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001198eefeb _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001198f0645 _dispatch_once_callout + 66
7   FirebaseDatabase                    0x000000011267c39e +[NSRunLoop(FSRWebSocket) FSR_networkRunLoop] + 78
8   FirebaseDatabase                    0x00000001126758be -[FSRWebSocket _connect] + 78
9   FirebaseDatabase                    0x0000000112674562 -[FSRWebSocket open] + 258
10  FirebaseDatabase                    0x00000001126a409e -[FWebSocketConnection open] + 270
11  FirebaseDatabase                    0x0000000112614268 -[FConnection open] + 120
12  FirebaseDatabase                    0x000000011264ed4a -[FPersistentConnection openNetworkConnectionWithContext:] + 698
13  FirebaseDatabase                    0x000000011264e92b __45-[FPersistentConnection tryScheduleReconnect]_block_invoke_2 + 347
14  FirebaseDatabase                    0x000000011262671e __80-[FIRDatabaseConnectionContextProvider fetchContextForcingRefresh:withCallback:]_block_invoke.87 + 110
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001198edda8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001198eefeb _dispatch_client_callout + 8
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001198f6dd1 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 1064
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001198f7bab _dispatch_lane_invoke + 441
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000119905f63 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 959
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000119efcfd0 _pthread_wqthread + 326
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000119efbf57 start_wqthread + 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This priority inversion issue is fixed in the latest version (9.6.0) - [See release note with the issue thread](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#realtime-database).

> [Fixed] Fix priority inversion issue exposed by Xcode 14 (#10130).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32781186)